# Twilio - change SIP trunk through API

Tags: api, twilio, sip

Is it possible to change the Twilio SIP trunk of a phone number through Twilio API?
Ex: Move a number from Trunk 1 to Trunk 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that should work with these two parts of the [API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sip-trunking/api/phonenumber-resource):

## Remove number from old trunk

```js
// Download the helper library from https://www.twilio.com/docs/node/install
// Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
// and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.trunking.v1.trunks('TKXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
                  .phoneNumbers('PNXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
                  .remove();
```

## Add number to new trunk

```js
// Download the helper library from https://www.twilio.com/docs/node/install
// Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
// and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.trunking.v1.trunks('TKXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
                  .phoneNumbers
                  .create({
                     phoneNumberSid: 'PNXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
                   })
                  .then(phone_number => console.log(phone_number.sid));
```